# How to secure Blazor Server against cross-origin attacks?

Tags: websocket, cors, signalr, blazor-server-side

I would like to ensure that a Blazor Server app is secure against cross-origin attacks, in particular against the SignalR hub that Blazor Server is using. The app in question has no need to enable *any* cross-origin connections as far as I am aware.

Microsoft have a Blazor Server Threat Mitigation document, that states the need for Cross-origin protection (see here: [Threat Mitigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/threat-mitigation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cross-origin-protection)). This document suggests that "opening a malicious WebSocket is also possible" and that

> - Blazor Server apps can be accessed cross-origin unless additional
>   measures are taken to prevent it. To disable cross-origin access,
>   either disable CORS in the endpoint by adding the CORS middleware to
>   the pipeline and adding the DisableCorsAttribute to the Blazor
>   endpoint metadata or limit the set of allowed origins by configuring
>   SignalR for cross-origin resource sharing.
> - If CORS is enabled, extra
>   steps might be required to protect the app depending on the CORS
>   configuration. If CORS is globally enabled, CORS can be disabled for
>   the Blazor Server hub by adding the DisableCorsAttribute metadata to
>   the endpoint metadata after calling MapBlazorHub on the endpoint
>   route builder.

If I understand the above correctly, I need to "disable CORS in the endpoint by adding the CORS middleware to the pipeline and adding the DisableCorsAttribute to the Blazor endpoint metadata", but so far I have been unable to figure out how to do this. [Edit: I think my answer covers this part of the question.]

The above article also references another on SignalR security (see here: [Security considerations in ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-5.0#websocket-origin-restriction)) which says that "The protections provided by CORS don't apply to WebSockets. For origin restriction on WebSockets, read [WebSockets origin restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-5.0#websocket-origin-restriction)".

The article on WebSockets origin restriction describes how to configure cross origin protection for WebSockets, however this is not explained in the context of configuring the WebSockets used by Blazor Server and I am yet to figure out how to do this.

How do I ensure that my Blazor Server application is secure against cross origin requests to the SignalR hub via its WebSocket(s) or any other relevant connection mechanism(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have arrived at a solution. I'm not entirely happy with it, but it seems to do the job. This solution is in three parts:

1. Apply the DisableCorsAttribute to the Blazor endpoint as recommended in the docs.
2. Block cross-origin requests to the Blazor WebSockets endpoint.
3. Apply authorization to the Blazor endpoint (strictly speaking this has nothing to do with cross origin requests, but I thought it worth a mention here).

## 1. DisableCorsAttribute

In `Startup.ConfigureServices()` add `services.AddCors();` - I don't think I need to add a policy here, as I don't actually want to enable cors for any origins other than my own site.

In `Startup.Configure()` add `app.UseCors();` somewhere after `app.UseRouting();` but before `app.UseEndpoints();`

Use `WithMetadata()` to add `DisableCorsAttribute` to the Blazor endpoint metadata:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub().WithMetadata(new DisableCorsAttribute());
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

## 2. Block cross-origin requests to the Blazor WebSockets endpoint

CORS policies aren't applied to websockets (hence all the trouble). This solution seems a bit hacky, but it seems to work, I'm open to suggestions for improvements or better solutions. I have this at the top of the `Startup.Configure()` method so that cross-origin requests to the Blazor WebSockets endpoint will effectively just be ignored rather than have error codes returned to potential attackers.

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.Value == "/_blazor")
    {
        if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Origin", out var origin)
            && origin != $"https://{ context.Request.Host.Value }")
        {
            return; // Refuse to handle request
        }
    }
    await next();
});
```

## 3. Authorization

I'm already using OIDC cookie based authentication in this application, so it seemed worth applying authorization to the Blazor endpoint so that only authenticated users can access it. It's worth noting that this in its self does not provide protection against cross-origin attacks that might somehow get an authenticated user to run code that connects to our Blazor endpoint, as the OIDC cookies are SameSite=None out of necessity. It seems like protection worth applying as an addition though.

This is achieved by adding `.RequireAuthorization()` to `MapBlazorHub()`.

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub()
        .RequireAuthorization()
        .WithMetadata(new DisableCorsAttribute());
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```